# Getting and using a google glass oauth2 access token from an android app

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

I am trying to get a glass access token to post to the glass timeline from within an android application. the user is able to select some information and send that to his glass device.

```
String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(activity, mEmail, activity.getString(R.string.glass_token_scope));
```

where mEmail is the google glass user's Google Account email, and scope is:

```
oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/glass.timeline https://www.googleapis.com/auth/glass.location https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
```

(oauth2: ...)

I am using the Google AuthUtil and it does return an access token, too. But when I use the access token, the API responds with 401 Unauthorized:

```
D/demo    (10804): Response Code: 401
D/demo    (10804): {
D/demo    (10804):  "error": {
D/demo    (10804):   "errors": [
D/demo    (10804):    {
D/demo    (10804):     "domain": "global",
D/demo    (10804):     "reason": "authError",
D/demo    (10804):     "message": "Invalid Credentials",
D/demo    (10804):     "locationType": "header",
D/demo    (10804):     "location": "Authorization"
D/demo    (10804):    }
D/demo    (10804):   ],
D/demo    (10804):   "code": 401,
D/demo    (10804):   "message": "Invalid Credentials"
D/demo    (10804):  }
D/demo    (10804): }
```

I've successfully also setup the server-side Oauth2 flow and with the resulting access token I can successfully create a timeline post from a a little local script.

It really seems that the access token returned from the Android Authutil cannot be used with the Glass Mirror API. I checked back to the Google APIs console and see that you can create some Android specific client ids. So I created a client ID for an androdi application and also setup the simple API access for android. For the SHA1 fingerprint I used the debug certificate's SHA1.

Has anyone succeeded on getting a Glass token on Android and has been successfully making a request from the android phone with that token?

For the actual request I using a plain HttpURLConnection - could that be the issue?

```
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(URI_TIMELINE).openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        con.getOutputStream().write(content.toString().getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a valid OAuth 2.0 token on Android, you will need to use the Google Play Services APIs, especially the [GoogleAuthUtil](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html) class.

You will also need to register your certificate on the [APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console); I would suggest checking out the [Drive SDK Quickstart for Android](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android) that describes those steps.

Comment: Hi Alain, I am using the GoogleAuthUtil class  -you can see it in the code snipped I posted. I also get an access token, all works so far. but when I use this access token, which was created using the correct glass scopes, I get a 401 Not Authorized from the server.

Comment: I have now switched to the server side - e.g. I pass an identifier in a call to a private proxy server and the proxy server (app engine) performs the call against the google mirror api. It works...

Comment: I've also created a oauth2 cleint id and used the settings form "installed application"  - I also added the package name and the sha1 fingerprint. I guess the problem is that I then perform "manual" REST API calls. In those calls, I nowhere do set the SHA1 Fingerprint for example. I assume the Google APIs do this automtically. Is there a way to do this manually? I want to use the REST api myself, I don't want to use a provided API that does many things without my control.

Comment: Once you get the token from GoogleAuthUtil, you should be set to use it the way you want. You can also try to [validate your token](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent#validatetoken) to make sure it was issued for your Android app and not a generic app.